# scale an svg background-image to fit the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a simple div container with a certain height and width. I need an `svg` image to serve as a background image for an `::after` of my div.

these are the styles of my `::after`

```
    &:after{
        content:'';
        background-image: url('../images/svg/triangle_blue.svg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: auto auto;
        position:absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        display:inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

this is what the head of my svg looks like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 50 100" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

Now I want the svg always scale scale to fit the `::after` container.
What am I missing?

Comment: just a thought, have you tried `background-size: contain` ? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: @valepu I have tried every possible value-type for background-size. No change at all. Somehow it still preservs the aspect Ratio

Comment: can you show us a page or a plunker/jsfiddle with the issue?

Comment: A demo would be useful. Obviously there is something else going on.

Comment: try adding an actual percentage to `background-size:` like `100% 100%` you may need to go larger than the container like `105%` also you can remove the inline styles on the svg which may be over-riding the `background-size:` property you are giving

Answer (score 2):

Found out a working solution. This is my `svg` code now:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 50 100" width="100%" height="100%" enable-background="new 0 0 50 100" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none"><g><polygon fill="#009EE0" points="0 100 50 50 0 0 "/></g></svg>
```

css:

```
background-size: auto auto;
```

seems like the only difference here is the

> xml:space="preserve"

in the `svg`

Comment: xml:space="preserve" only has an effect on text elements and you don't have any of those.